# UItableView delegate called mutiple times in swift

Tags: uitableview, delegates, swift2

This is my custom UITableViewController, I added any other code and the delegates methods are called five times

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("numberOfSectionsInTableView called")
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("numberOfRowsInSection called for section => \(section)")
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "hey"
        return cell
    }

}
```

the logs:

numberOfSectionsInTableView called
numberOfSectionsInTableView called
numberOfRowsInSection called for section => 0
numberOfSectionsInTableView called
numberOfRowsInSection called for section => 0
numberOfSectionsInTableView called
numberOfRowsInSection called for section => 0
numberOfSectionsInTableView called
numberOfRowsInSection called for section => 0
numberOfSectionsInTableView called
numberOfRowsInSection called for section => 0

**EDIT**

it's the only class which I launch from the appDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    if let window = window {

        let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.viewControllers = [Test()]
        window.rootViewController = nav
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: at some point in your code, something calls reloadData amy I wrong ? Or your UItableviewcontroller is instantiated twice. or your delegate is set on the wrong object

Comment: Yes, probably but it's unbelievable: I doubled check everything, my viewdidload is called only once and there is nothing else in this controller

Comment: btw you should use storyboard

Comment: no, I encountered more problems with storyboard than without.

Comment: I know it sucks I've done most of my projects withouts but it's a good thing especially if someone else will have to work on your project later on.

Answer (score 0):

Table view data source methods may get called multiple times. There is no guarantee on number of times it gets called. Due to the the implementation of `UITableView` there are many situations where certain delegate/datasource methods will get called twice or more because the table view has to refresh something. This includes situations like **reloading table view, changing table header view** etc. So, you might want to check your implementation on such cases!